# How to change agents roles

Tags: netlogo

I am new to netlogo and I really need somebodys help.My issue is: I am trying to do simulation with 3 sets of agents: firms, officers and citizens. The thing is: Together,I have 10 persons / turtles  and I need them to be divided into these 3 sets, but I also need than, at the beginnig,each turtle can choose to which set of agents he wants to belong.......... So each time I will click on setup bottom, agents can change their role.
Thanks for a help. Erika
My code is:

```
breed [firms firm]
breed [ officers officer]
breed [ citizens citizen]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles num-of-firms[  
    set color blue
    set xcor random-xcor
    set ycor random-ycor
    ]
  create-turtles num-of-officers [ 
   set color green
   set xcor random-xcor
   set ycor random-ycor
   ]
  create-turtles num-of-citizens [ 
   set color white
   set xcor random-xcor
   set ycor random-ycor
  ] 
 set-default-shape turtles "person" 
 reset ticks
```

end

Answer (score 3):

Each NetLogo turtle has a built-in [`breed` variable](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#breedvar) that you can use to dynamically change the breed of a turtle.

If you wanted to create some total number of agents (e.g., 100) and have each them choose at random which breed it belongs to, you could do:

```
breed [ firms firm]
breed [ officers officer]
breed [ citizens citizen]

to setup
  clear-all
  set-default-shape turtles "person" 
  create-turtles 100 [  
    set xcor random-xcor
    set ycor random-ycor
  ]
  ask turtles [ 
    set breed one-of (list firms officers citizens)
  ]
  ask firms [ set color blue ]
  ask officers [ set color green ]
  ask citizens [ set color white ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

Comment: And if I want  that each breed (firms, officers and citizens) will have that same number of agents, what should I add to the code?

Comment: Well then you can use the [`create-<breeds>`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#create-breeds) variant of `create-turtles`. There is no need to have the turtles themselves choose which breed they should belong to. Is that what you wanted in the first place?

Comment: @Erika you might want to accept the answer then? :)